# How to select all shapes with a specific word in their name

Tags: excel, vba, select, shapes

I want to select and hide shapes with a specific word in their name.

I'm making a map using Excel.

I have a macro that inserts a pin/new shape in the top right corner of the map that you then drag to the right place in the map.

The macro gives a new name to each new pin/shape.
For example A23_AXR42_Towncar
A23 is the sequential order of the shape (i.e this was the 23rd shape that was inserted)
AXR42 is the id number of the car
Towncar is the category

In total there will be seven categories of pins.
New pins will be added.
I need to select all shapes in one sheet that has the word Towncar in their name. So when I click a button it selects all the shapes and then hides/shows them using the pane window.

I recorded a macro by choosing all shapes containing a certain word in the name.
The problem is that it selects all shapes based on their name.
I need it to choose all shapes that have "towncar" in the name.

```vb
Sub Select_towncar_shapes()
'
' Select_towncar_shapes Makro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A19_XRT44_Towncar")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A19_XRT44_Towncar", "A23_ZWE18_Towncar")). _
        Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A19_XRT44_Towncar", "A23_ZWE18_Towncar", _
        "A20_VBV77_Towncar")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A19_XRT44_Towncar", "A23_ZWE18_Towncar", _
        "A20_VBV77_Towncar", "A24_RTC53_Towncar")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A24_RTC53_Towncar")).Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A23_ZWE18_Towncar")).Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A20_VBV77_Towncar")).Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A19_XRT44_Towncar")).Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A19_XRT44_Towncar")).Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A20_VBV77_Towncar")).Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A23_ZWE18_Towncar")).Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A24_RTC53_Towncar")).Visible = msoTrue
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add what code you have to the question. A starting point makes it more likely someone answers your question

Comment: I edited my post and inserted the cod that i got when i tried to record the macro

Answer (score 3):

The following routine will show or hide all shapes of a worksheet where the shape name contain a specific word. There is no need to *select* any shape and set the visibility manually:

```
Sub ShowHideShapes(ws As Worksheet, word As String, show As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        If InStr(1, sh.Name, word, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            sh.Visible = show
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now put 2 buttons on your sheet, one to show and one to hide the shapes. The code for this buttons would be

```
Sub buttonShow_click()
    ShowHideShapes ActiveSheet, "Towncar", True
End Sub

Sub buttonHide_click()
    ShowHideShapes ActiveSheet, "Towncar", False
End Sub
```

Note that you can also use shapes to execute macros, just place them on the sheet, right click on it and use "Assign Macro".

If you want to show and hide other shapes with different names, simply change the 2nd parameter from `"Towncar"` to whatever you want to show or hide.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out :D

just to clarify, do i first make a macro with first code and then make two more for each button? do i need to connect the first code to the buttons as well. ?

Comment: The first code is a general routine that can be used to show/hide shapes with *any* name on *any* worksheet. For every button you have, you need one routine that simply contains a call to this general routine with the wanted parameters.

Comment: got it to work thanks again. Now on to next issue to solve.

Answer (score 2):

### Show/Hide Shapes

**The Calling Procedures**

```vb
Sub ShowTownCar()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ShowHideShapes "TownCar", wb, "Sheet1"
End Sub

Sub HideTownCar()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ShowHideShapes "TownCar", wb, "Sheet1", True
End Sub
```

**The Called Procedure (Method)**

```vb
Sub ShowHideShapes( _
        ByVal EndsWith As String, _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        Optional ByVal WorksheetName As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal DoHide As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:
    If Len(WorksheetName) = 0 Then
        Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(WorksheetName)
    End If
    
    Dim eLen As Long: eLen = Len(EndsWith)
    
    Dim dict As Object, shp As Shape, shpName As String, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        shpName = shp.Name
        If Len(shpName) >= eLen Then
            If StrComp(Right(shp.Name, eLen), EndsWith, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If Not IsFirstFound Then
                    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                    IsFirstFound = True
                End If
                dict(shpName) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
  
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No shapes ending with """ & EndsWith & """ found.", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub ' no shapes found
    End If
    
    ws.Shapes.Range(dict.Keys).Visible = Not DoHide

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it as easy as possible.
Better to give the name as argument but for a beginner this one is easier

```
Public Sub SelectShapesByName()
        Dim i As Long
        Dim f() As Variant, z As Long
        Dim StepField As Long
             Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        On Error GoTo errExit
        StepField = 5
        ReDim f(StepField)
        z = -1
        For i = 1 To ws.Shapes.Count
            On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Shapes(i).Type <> 4 Then
                If ws.Shapes(i).Name Like "*Towncar*" Then ' Here is the name
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then
                        z = z + 1
                        If z > StepField Then
                            StepField = StepField + 5
                            ReDim Preserve f(StepField)
                        End If
                        f(z) = i
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    
    On Error GoTo errExit
    If z > -1 Then
        If UBound(f) <> z Then ReDim Preserve f(z)
        ws.Shapes.Range(f).Select
    End If
    Exit Sub
    errExit:
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much what a star :D I have been trying to find a work around for this for a couple of days now and you did within an hour.

Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub select_towncar_shapes()
  select_shapes "towncar"
End Sub

Sub hide_towncar_shapes()
  shapes_visibility "towncar", False
End Sub

Sub show_towncar_shapes()
  shapes_visibility "towncar", True
End Sub

Sub shapes_visibility(includedStr As String, is_visible As Boolean)
  Dim sht As Worksheet:         Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
  Dim shapes_array() As String: shapes_array = get_shapes_array(sht, includedStr)
  
  On Error Resume Next
  sht.Shapes.Range(shapes_array).Visible = is_visible
End Sub

Sub select_shapes(includedStr As String)
  Dim sht As Worksheet:         Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
  Dim shapes_array() As String: shapes_array = get_shapes_array(sht, includedStr)
  
  On Error Resume Next
  sht.Shapes.Range(shapes_array).Select
End Sub
 
Function get_shapes_array(sht As Worksheet, includedStr As String) As String()
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim output() As String
  Dim arrayCount As Long
  
  For Each shp In sht.Shapes
    If InStr(1, shp.Name, includedStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      arrayCount = arrayCount + 1
      ReDim Preserve output(1 To arrayCount)
      output(arrayCount) = shp.Name
    End If
  Next shp
  get_shapes_array = output
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much for quick replie :D i will try this out as well.